# Latest deployment message for application(s) with CloudBees SDK in run@cloud

Tags: cloudbees

The command *bees app:list* shows names of the applications, status, URL and instance count, but is there a way to see the latest commit message?

We set the commit message to be the Git revision of the sources that produce the deployed WAR and it would be nice to see which version is currently running of each app without having to look it from the RUN console wep application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bees app:info shows a bit more information but not that deploy message, unfortunately. That may be a nice addition to it thought, I will pass that on.

bees app:info will show exact deployment time, if that helps.